# Why does the date formatter fails?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a date string in the following format
**"2017-02-10T07:45:00.000Z"**

I am using the following format
**let flightStatusDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ"**

But when I run the app the dateFormatter returns a nil NSDate object.
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: because the `T` is missing some `'` around it: `'T'`

Comment: So does the final `Z`, because Z is the time zone formatted like +0000

Comment: use following time format :  yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be,

```
let flightStatusDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please escape the `T` and the `Z`:

`let flightStatusDateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"`

If you don't, the Z will be considered as the TimeZone, and the T will be unrecognized.